# Android Admob not showing in emulator it is blank

Tags: java, android, admob

I have been following the android quick start tutorial https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start to put Admob on the emulator and it is not working what could be missing.I have essentially copied the tutorial word for word and it does not work.Also I have checked my Logcat and got this error **Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager',referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza** . That seems to be an internal error with them.I have also just upgraded to the new Android Studio 1.2.1.1 for what it is worth .Here is my basic code

**Main.java**

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

**acitivity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Main">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
}
```

**Strings XML**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">AdsenseCalculator</string>
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)    // remove when exporting signed APK
        .addTestDevice(getDeviceId())       // remove when exporting signed APK
        .build();
```

Comment: Thank you that worked specifically the  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();